# How to read XML Nodes in XML using c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a XML file like below:

```
<report timestamp="3201" reportVersion="2" request="3981135340">
<question timedOut="false" time="3163" attempts="2" correct="true" id="13"> 
<answer status="attempt"> 
<radioButton correct="false" value="true" id="17" /> 
</answer> 
<answer status="correct"> 
<radioButton correct="true" value="true" id="15" /> 
</answer> 
</question> 
</report>
```

I want to read the child nodes based on 'status' attribute of 'answer' node.

Answer (score 4):

Use [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) (fastest but forward only), [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (LINQ to XML) or [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28VS.80%29.aspx). See the examples in the msdn documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ to XML:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // or XDocument.Load()
var elements = from e in doc.Descendants("answer")
               where e.Attribute("status").Value == "attempt"
               select e;

// elements will be IEnumerable<XElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlDocument and XPath:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
//here you should load your xml for example with document.Load();
XmlNodeList nodes = document.SelectNodes("/report/question/answer[@status = 'correct']/radioButton");
```

Just modify the XPath to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
foreach (XmlNode xnode in xdoc.SelectNodes("report/question/answer"))
    {
        if (xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("status").Value == "correct")
        {
            string value = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("report/question/answer[@status='correct']/radioButton").Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;

        }
        if (xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("status").Value == "attempt")
        {
            string value = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("report/question/answer[@status='attempt']/radioButton").Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;
        }
    }
```